# Migrate Documents to Another Collection

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrj, solrcloud

I have a solr collections on the merger, we would like to ask the next question is as follows
I have two collections, c1 and c2,

C1 colleciton there are 10 data, id is from c1_0 to c1_9,

C2 colleciton also has 10 data, id is from c2_0 to c2_9,

I now want to c1 id c1_ format data into the c2, I implemented the following order, it seems no effect, and why?

I c1 designated in the new **router.field=id**

http://localhost:8081/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=c1&numShards=3&replicationFactor=3&maxShardsPerNode=3&collection.configName=myconf&router.field=id

I refer to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api12

Solr version 6.3.0

I have a problem? Or understanding wrong?

Comment: Migrating [documents is done with the MIGRATE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api12) command. Are you trying to migrate documents to a different collection, or create a new collection (which is what your command attempts to do)?

Comment: I have just tried to create a c3, c1 also create the same order is not specified router.field = id parameters, c2 has not specified, ask you a thing, I use the right?
`Http: // localhost: 8081 / solr / admin / collection? Action = MIGRATE & collection = c1 & split.key = c1_ & target.collection = c3`

Split.key is **c1_** or **c1!** ?

But the data is not how the past is going on, I see the c1 state.json document which has **routingRules** node

Comment: Some people know? Is this solr Bug or I understand it wrong?